# How to watch and task an dynamic list of sources with gulp / browsersync or something alike

Tags: npm, gulp, npm-scripts

I am running an gulpfile with file watching functionality and BrowserSync.

I am looking for a way to dynamically change the source array of an task without restarting all tasks/watches/processes/server. I currently use Gulp for my build proces but any of the like that has this functionality would be great.

Example:

```
gulp.task('scripts', () =>
     gulp.src(['js/file1.js'])
        .pipe(...)
        .pipe(...)
)
```

change to

```
gulp.task('scripts', () =>
     gulp.src(['js/file1.js', 'js/file2.js', 'js/file3.js'])
        .pipe(...)
        .pipe(...)
)
```

without reloading the browsersync process and other gulp.watch functions.

Comment: What's wrong with just using `js/*.js`?

Comment: Nothing. But in my usecase i need it to be specific and dynamic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put all paths that you want to be dynamic in a file `paths.json`:

```
{
  "scriptFiles": ["js/file1.js"]
}
```

In your `gulpfile.js` add a function `paths()` that reads and parses the JSON file:

```
var fs = require('fs');

function paths() {
  return JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('paths.json'));
}
```

In your tasks use that function to access the paths you have defined in `paths.json`:

```
gulp.task('scripts', () =>
  return gulp.src(paths().scriptFiles)
    .pipe(...)
    .pipe(...)
);
```

Now you can just edit the value of the `"scriptFiles"` property in `paths.json` and the next time your `scripts` task runs it will use the updated value.